# Are there file upload limits drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, view, content-type

I had someone create a content type "documents page". When we create a "documents page" we can create a category and or subcategory. Then we can upload a file in that category or subcategory. In return the page shows a list of files grouped by the category we put them in, along with some fields (date, link ect).

The problem is once we add about 100 documents the page will error out and not display anything anymore. The info is there in the edit sceen but there is an ajax error. The developer says 100 is the limit of entries that can be added.

Does this sound like there is a possible solution? I have the php resources up pretty high. Are there limits and or can they be overidden?

Comment: there's php limits, there's apache limits, and there's whatever limits drupal itself adds.

Comment: Park, can you please display the ajax error message that appears?

Comment: Joel Hernandez, thank you here is the error Notice: Undefined index: #ajax in ajax_form_callback()(line 395 of /var/www/vhost/oups.org/httpdocs/includes/ajax.inc)

Comment: Your error seems to relate to there being no `callback` function set for your `#ajax` item in the form. You can see the code throwing the error [HERE](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupal/tree/includes/ajax.inc?h=7.x#n395). How is your form created? Are you using the form api to create it?